# Merging two files by ignoring a line with AWK

Tags: awk, merging-data

I have two files: 
file 1:

```
a 1 2 3 
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
d 1 2 3
```

file 2:

```
hola
l m  n o p q
```

Now I want to merge them in one single file by ignoring the header of file 2 like this:

```
a 1 2 3 l m n o p q 
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
d 1 2 3
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if(NR>1)a[NR-1]=$0;next}{print $0,a[FNR]}' file2 file1
a 1 2 3 l m  n o p q 
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
d 1 2 3
```

Brief explanation,

- `NR==FNR{if(NR>1)a[NR-1]=$0;next}`: in file2, omit the header and save from the second record to a[NR-1]. *Note: this would also work as the lines in file2 grow up*
- `print $0,a[FNR]`: print the combination of the content of $0 in file1 and a[FNR]. FNR would be the record number in file1.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but  in my output I see 3l. No space between 3 and l.

Comment: @wara, see my modification. This should with a space between 3 and l.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding "\t", here '="\t"$0;next'

Answer (score 4):

Same expected output can be achieved without `awk` also

```
$ cat file1
a 1 2 3 
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
d 1 2 3

$ cat file2
hola
l m  n o p q 

$ pr -mtJS' '  file1 <(tail -n +2 file2)
a 1 2 3  l m  n o p q
b 1 2 3 
c 1 2 3 
d 1 2 3 

$ paste -d ' '  file1 <(tail -n +2 file2)
a 1 2 3  l m  n o p q 
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
d 1 2 3
```

Comment: Nice solutions Akshay.